# How can I make sure PHP is using TBinaryProtocolAccelerated

Tags: php5

How can I make sure PHP is using TBinaryProtocolAccelerated and not TBinaryProtocol as the protocol?

I am using PHP5 in Ubuntu Server.

Comment: Your Thrift question is probably better placed on StackOverflow.

Comment: I though this had something to do with server admin. Am I wrong?

Comment: TBinaryProtocol and TBinaryProtocolAccelerated are protocol flavors of Thrift. So it's not specific to PHP, nor Apache httpd, nor Ubuntu Linux.